# A simple problem on probability

Tags: probability

Suppose we have a train running on a railroad from $A$ to $B$. The railroad is N Km long from the point $A$ to the point $B$ and the speed of the train is $v$ $Km/h$. We have two situations: in the first one, we know for sure the train will derail with a probability $p_0\lt1$ between $A$ and $B$. In the second one we know for sure the train will derail in the section $\overline{AB}$ with probability $p_1=1$. What is the probability to derail versus time $t$ in the two cases assuming the train strarts from $A$ with speed $v$? Thanks.

Comment: To clarify... are we assuming the train is equally likely to derail at any point?

Comment: @Mathmo123: exatly

Comment: Then won't this just be a uniform distribution on $[0,N]$? The probability it has derailed by $m$km will be $\frac {p_i}m$

Comment: @Mathmo123: In the first case and in the second I suppose the probability vs. time isn't a uniform distribution.

Comment: Can you justify that? In case 2 for example, the train is guaranteed to stop on the way, and equally likely to stop at any point. So the distribution is uniform.

Comment: @Mathmo123: in the second case, the probability to derail in the last 10 meters is greater than the probability to derail in the last 100 meters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each case, the train derails with probability $p$, and does not derail with probability $1-p$.

Given that the train derails, where it derails is *uniform*. To see this, let's rephrase the question: imagine a line going from $0$ to $1$. You take $1$ minute to run your finger along the line *at a constant speed* until I say stop - which I must say at some point. I say stop at a random point.

From my perspective, I pick a random real number $x$ in $[0,1]$ and say stop after $x$ minutes. This will be a uniform choice. I am no more likely to say "stop" in the last 5 seconds than I am in the first.

In answer to your comment "in the second case, the probability to derail in the last 10 meters is greater than the probability to derail in the last 100 meters", that's not fully accurate.. You are correct that **given that it did not stop before that point** the probability that it will stop in the last 100 metres is large. However, that is a conditional probability. From the beginning, however, it is equally likely to stop at any point.

Hence, in your case, the probability it has derailed by $m$ kilometres given that it does derail will be $\frac mN$ and hence, the final probability will be $\frac {pm}N$.

Comment: Perhaps it's a conditional probability he seeks though?

Comment: In the second case, the probability the train 'does not' derail is: $q=1-\frac{vt}{N}$, I suppose, so it's strongly dependent on the point on the railroad.

Comment: Please can you explain how you got to that?